# Android: Set Chat State Notifications in Beem App

Tags: android, xmpp

I am currently using [Beem's](http://beem-project.com) source code to do developments. I would like to implement the chat state notifications. I have look through the codes and found that there is a setState() method, but I believe it has not been implemented and I have no clues about how to do it. If I use Adium to type a message to the Beem user, the Beem user is able to see that the Adium user is composing a message. But if both users are using Beem, then it does not display if the user is composing a message. Therefore, I would like to try to implement the chat state notification. How do I go about doing it? Is there any guides out there? Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to **setState** method in **ChatAdapter.java** file.

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message message = new org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message();
    ChatStateExtension extension = null;
    switch (state) {
        case "composing":
            extension = new ChatStateExtension(ChatState.composing);
            break;
        case "active":
            extension = new ChatStateExtension(ChatState.active);
            break;
        case "inactive":
            extension = new ChatStateExtension(ChatState.inactive);
            break;
        case "gone":
            extension = new ChatStateExtension(ChatState.gone);
            break;
        case "paused":
            extension = new ChatStateExtension(ChatState.paused);
            break;
    }
    message.addExtension(extension);
    try {
        mAdaptee.sendMessage(message);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```